# Formal Proving Discrete maths

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Prove using logical equivalence rules/laws that

$$~[ ∧ ~ ∧ ( ∨ )] ∨ (~ ∧ ) ∧ ~( ∨ ~ ∨ ~) ≡ ~ ∨ b$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried?

Comment: i basically tried solving it but i keep using the wrong rules, i really need help, i'm stuck!!

Comment: take your time and write the work more neatly and argue about each rule you use @caitlin

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll prove the left to right half using a semantic argument, have your truth tables ready to check my reasoning:

1. A basic principle of disjunction (POD):

$$\Gamma, \phi \lor \psi \vDash \chi \;\;\; \text{iff} \;\;\; \Gamma,\phi \vDash \chi \,\,\, \text{and} \,\,\, \Gamma,\psi \vDash \chi$$

2. A basic principle of conjunction (POC):

$$\Gamma \vDash \phi \land \psi \;\;\; \text{iff} \;\;\; \Gamma \vDash \phi \,\,\, \text{and} \,\,\, \Gamma \vDash \psi$$

3. Deduction Teorem (DT):

$$\Gamma \vDash \phi \to \psi \;\;\; \text{iff} \;\;\; \Gamma,\phi\vDash\psi$$

Also: POD implies this introduction rule:

$$\phi \vDash \phi \lor \psi$$

And obviously assumption (Ass):
$$ \phi \vDash \phi$$

---

First consider the Assumption: $\Gamma,[a \land b \land (a \lor c) ]\vDash [(a \land b) \land (a \lor c) ]$; by POC we get: $$\Gamma,[a \land b \land (a \lor c) ]\vDash a\land b$$ and with another application of POC we obtain: $$\Gamma,[(a \land b) \land (a \lor c) ]\vDash a$$

Therefore, using the introduction rule: $$\Gamma,[(a \land b) \land (a \lor c) ]\vDash a \lor b.$$

Now consider (Ass): $\Gamma,[( a \land b) \land (a \lor b \lor c)] \vDash( a \land b) \land (a \lor b \lor c)$; with a simple use of POC we obtain: $$\Gamma, [( a \land b) \land (a \lor b \lor c)]\vDash a\land b$$

And thus with an equivalent argument we deduce: $$\Gamma,[( a \land b) \land (a \lor b \lor c)]\vDash a \lor b.$$

Now we use POD to obtain the formula:

$$\Gamma, \, [a \land b \land (a \lor c) ] \, \lor \, [( a \land b) \land (a \lor b \lor c)] \vDash a \lor b  $$

And finally we use the deduction theorem to get the first result we want:

$$\Gamma \vDash \{[a \land b \land (a \lor c) ] \, \lor \, [( a \land b) \land (a \lor b \lor c)]\} \to a \lor b$$

---

Now you must start from $a \lor b$ and deduce $[a \land b \land (a \lor c) ] \, \lor \, [( a \land b) \land (a \lor b \lor c)]$.